# How to set width webview wrap content in item recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, webview

I need show list object have string html so I use WebView in item RecyclerView.
I want width of WebView in item can `wrap_content` so I add a java interface in WebView and in HTML I added a function javascript to get width content HTML, after that I will set layout params for WebView.
It worked, but sometime function get width return fail.
My app in here [WebViewInRecyclerView](https://github.com/thangkho/WebViewInRecyclerView)

How I can fix my bug.
If you have another ideal for WebView `wrap_content` with please share with me.
Thank yout so much
[image]

Comment: `sometime function get width return fail`, can you post function `get width` here and describe more about fail

Comment: You can check in here https://github.com/thangkho/WebViewInRecyclerView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bklabs/webviewinrecyclerview/MyListAdapter.java
Example: my content is `https://google.com` but ` get width` return `22px`.

Comment: when getWidth = 22px, `screenWith` = ? and `withContent` = ?

Comment: In exactly my fail case screenWith = 1440, get width return 33 and exactly width is 295. 33 is witdh of another item.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `RecyclerView` will recycle view for performance.
Therefore, you need to set the width of your WebView from your `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: I try addJavaInterface in onBindViewHolder but it return same result.

Comment: can you apply it toyour code in github then I can check. (you can create new branch for it)

Comment: I did it. please check in `master`

Comment: in your onBindViewHolder, the method `getWidthContent` is never used, then your webview width can not set